# (c++) Elements of Array into String?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Can somebody help me in converting some elements of `char array[]` into `String`.
I'm still learning strings.

```
char input[40] = "save filename.txt";
int j;
string check;
for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
   if (input[i] == ' ')
   {
      j = i+1;
      break;
   }
}
int index;
for (int m = 0; arr[j] != '\0'; m++)
{
    check[m] = arr[j];
    j++;
    index = m; //to store '\0' in string ??
}
check[index] = '\0';
cout << check; //now, String should output 'filename.txt" only
```

Comment: Not a very well-formed question -- what have you tried? And what didn't work about it?

Comment: I don't think that edit by Houssem should have been approved. Changed `string` to `String` and removed a potential example.

Comment: @crashmstr he is newbye and should learn write correctly and not to put non-informative lines

Comment: @HoussemBdr and when is a `string` `String`? Your changes were not significantly better in my opinion, and I would not have approved them had I seen them before they took place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string class has a constructor that takes a NULL-terminated C-string:

```
char arr[ ] = "filename.txt";

string str(arr);


//  You can also assign directly to a string.

str = "filename.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

The ctor of `std::string` has some useful overloads for constructing a string from a `char` array. The overloads are about equivalent to the following when used in practice:

- **Taking a pointer to constant `char`, i.e. a null-terminated C-string.**

  ```
  string(const char* s);
  ```

  The `char` array must be terminated with the null character, e.g. `{'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'}`. String literals in C++ is always automatically null-terminated, e.g. `"abc"` returns a `const char[4]` with elements `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`.
- **Taking a pointer to constant `char` and specified number of characters to copy.**

  ```
  string(const char* s, size_type count);
  ```

  Same as above but only `count` number of characters will be copied from the `char` array argument. The passed `char` array does not necessarily have to be null-terminated.
- **Taking 2 iterators.**

  ```
  string(InputIt first, InputIt last);
  ```

  Can be used to construct a string from a range of characters, e.g.

  ```
  const char[] c = "character array";
  std::string s{std::next(std::begin(c), 10), std::end(c)}; // s == "array".
  ```